# Fragment lifecylce behaviour using ViewPager2 and FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, exoplayer, android-viewpager2

I am displaying 5 `fragments` using `ViewPager2` and `FragmentStateAdapter`. Each `fragment` has `ExoPlayer` instance. I am maintaining `ViewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` and it is working well for loading `fragments`. However, when I scroll down the `ViewPager2` to `pos4`, `pos2` and `pos1` are supposed to call  `onStop()` ,  `onDestroyView()`, `onDestroy()`. But that is not happening.

None of these methods are executing unless I press `onBackPress()`. Is there anything I am missing with the implementation part of `FragmentStateAdapter`.

I want to perform `exoPlayer.release()` on `onDestroyView()` to free the memory of the application.

**Here is the code**

**Activity**

```
List<Post> postsList = response.getPosts();
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, postsList);
binding.pager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
binding.pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
binding.pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private List<Post> postList;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, List<Post> postList) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
        this.postList = postList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return new PostFragment(postList.get(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (postList == null) return 0;
        return postList.size();
    }

}
```

**Updated**

[This is also a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845042/how-does-fragments-lifecycle-works-inside-viewpager-why-onstop-is-not-called-o)

Comment: Did you try releasing the exo player instance in onDestroy instead of onDestroyView?

Comment: @ParagPawar I removed the previous comments to avoid confusion. Finally, I got a satisfying solution. Please refer to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

**I have referred this**  [POST](https://juejin.im/post/5cda3964f265da035d0c9d8f)  **for the solution.**

`VeiwPager2` is built on `RecyclerView` component and `FragmentStateAdapter` replaces `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Assuming `offscreenPageLimit = 1`,  `ViewPager2` will have **3**`fragments` and **2** `fragments` preloaded/cached by [RecylerView Preloading Strategies](https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710) So, there will be total **5** `fragments` loaded.

To disable preloading and caching, I performed:

```
private void disableCacheOfViewPager() {

    try {

      // Disable Preloading
        ((RecyclerView) binding.pager.getChildAt(0)).getLayoutManager().setItemPrefetchEnabled(false);
        // Disable Cache
        ((RecyclerView) binding.pager.getChildAt(0)).setItemViewCacheSize(0);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        Log.i(TAG, "disableCacheOfViewPager: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

> Scroll Logs Before

```
//1st
onStart: 0
onResume: 0
onStart: 1

//2nd
onStart: 2
onPause: 0
onResume: 1

//3rd
onStart: 3
onPause: 1
onResume: 2

//4th
onStart: 4
onPause: 2
onResume: 3

//5th
onStart: 5
onStop: 0
onDestroyView: 0
onDestroy: 0
onDetach: 0
onPause: 3
onResume: 4
```

> Scroll Logs After

```
//1st
onStart: 0
onResume: 0
onStart: 1

//2nd
onStart: 2
onPause: 0
onResume: 1

//3rd
onStart: 3
onStop: 0
onDestroyView: 0
onDestroy: 0
onDetach: 0
onPause: 1
onResume: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and it's a bug listed in googles page. I am not sure of the solution, but one approach is to forget using `ViewPager2` all together and go back to: `ViewPager & FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Seems to work fine in the old implementation.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154541095